# How can i verify that a element is in my array?

Tags: javascript, authentication

I'm making a simple login system for a school project and I need to verify if the usernames and passwords are in my list, but i can't seem to figure it out

```
var logs = [
    {
        username: "admin",
        senha: "admin"
    },

    {
        username: "client",
        senha: "client"
    }
]


function login_func() {
    let user =  document.getElementById('email_val')
    let passwd =  document.getElementById('passwd')

    if(logs.includes(user.value)){
        alert('amogus')
    }
    
}
```

If anyone could help I'd be really thankfull

Comment: Authenticating front-end is a big mistake. With the use of developer tools anyone can find the username of every account.

Comment: You can't use `includes()` to look for a string in array of objects. Use `find()`

Comment: `const matches = logs.filter( e => e.username == user.value && e.senha == passwd.value );` - how to deal with the possibility of multiple matches is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

the best practice for this one will be the `some` prototype of an array:

```
    function isVerify(username, password){
    
        return logs.some(log => log.password === password && log.username === username)

    }
```

Of course, in the real world, you will encrypt passwords, and store them in DBs.

In case you want to return the logged-in user, use `find` instead:

```
    function login(username, password){
    
        return logs.find(log => log.password === password && log.username === username)

    }
```

This will return null in case of unmatch result.

Comment: Write , instead of &&, corrected it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the equivalent of `includes` but you need to check for a property of each object, use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which takes a test function.

```js
if (logs.some(obj => obj.username === user.value && obj.senha === passwd.value)) {
```

---

Of course, keep in mind that this type of 'authentication' will only serve for demonstration purposes and will never actually be useful for a real login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find your user exists with your inputs.

```
const haveUser = (username, password) => !!logs.find(log => log.username == username && log.senha === password)
```

**Important** : When we wanna create an authentication system, should not create it on the Frontend side. It's completely wrong and risky because other developers open Dev Tools and can find your credentials.